# Homotopy lifting property with respect to a space $X$

Tags: algebraic-topology

A know about the geometrical interpretation and some applications of $homotopy$ $lifting$ $property$ but I'm unable to grasp the concept $homotopy$ $lifting$ $property$ $with$ $respect$ $a$ $space$ $X$. Can anybody make me understand?

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Can you be more specific  and use it in a sentence?

Comment: One is general, one is specific.

Comment: Take $X=\{0\}$ as the 1-point space for some simple geometric intuition.